# combine checkbox values using php mysql

Tags: php, sql

I having around 20 check boxes in my form as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="c3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="c4" value="4" />
```

i would like to these values to a database. I just thought rather than creating 20 fields in my database grab all the values at store in the db as 1,2,3,4 and then when querying to explode the values and display it accordingly using php.

can someone please tell me how am i supposed to concatenate the values 1,2,3,4 from the check fields when submitted so i can pass to the database.

i would appreciate if anyone can suggest a different effective way to achieve this using php.

Comment: Why not create a table for the question type like `type_id | type_name`. Then the answers table will have something `answer_id | type_id | answer`?

Comment: This is an sql antipattern, @Shef pointed the correct way to solve this problem... let me see if I can find a reference tutorial...

Comment: @Shef I actually don't knw how to do it, reference will be very useful..

Comment: @LiveEn: I already gave you rough idea of how. What do you not know how to do, alter a table schema? What kind of reference do you want me to give you? :)

Comment: Figured it out.. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the name of the checkboxes to be the same, something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="2" />
```

Then access them via `$_GET` or `$_POST` via

```
if (isset($_POST['cb'])) {
    $my_values = implode(",", $_POST['cb']);
}
```

If you want them sorted, then you will want to do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['cb'])) {
    $my_values = $_POST['cb'];
    sort($my_values);
    $my_db_value = implode(',', $my_values);
}
```

For the record, I agree with @Shef in the case that the database can handle the extra load.  Depending on when this information will be needed in a highly scalable solution, however, this is a perfectly acceptable way to handle this.

Comment: What will be the extra load? Records are easy to maintain, and data like this can sit all like a giant maglev train on memory, ready for you to sip it out. I don't think having all the records on one column will not scale.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your initial question, first off you need to name your checkboxes all the same name, so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="1" />
....
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="20" />
```

PHP script:

```
$boxes = $_POST['box'];
$values = implode(",", $boxes); // $values now has "1,2,3,4...", insert into table
```

A better way would be to have a separate table (see @Shef 's comment).