# MYSQL column select based on checkbox and group by checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to select columns from a mysql table based on checkboxes (columns provided as check boxes).  The following is a reproducible example.

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
<div>    
     <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="ZONE"><label>ZONE</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="STATE"><label>STATE</label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</div>

    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
        $checkboxes = isset($_POST['check_list']) ? $_POST['check_list'] : array();
        foreach($checkboxes as $value) { 
          echo $value,','; //selected value
        $sql = "SELECT $value,sum(RICEPDS) as 'CEREALS' from ck group by $value" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);  
        }}}
      ?>

  <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <?php
                  if (!$result) {
                        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
                    }
                    $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
                      for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
                        {
                            $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
                            echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
                        }
               ?> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          ?>
          <tr>
            <?php
              foreach($row as $cell)
                  echo "<td>$cell</td>";
            ?>
          </tr>
          <?php
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
          ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Understandably when I select one checkbox the table gets returned. When I select both the checkboxes, I am getting the error message echoed from this: `die("Query to show fields from table failed");`.

I think I have to get the last trailing comma from the $value.  How do I do it?

Comment: can you show what ouput are you getting after this print_r($checkboxes )

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: use mysqli_multi_query()  function

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link PHP mysqli_multi_query() Function https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420540/combine-checkbox-values-using-php-mysql)  I resolved this issue.  My working code is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
          $my_values = implode(",", $_POST['check_list']);
          $sql = "SELECT $my_values,sum(RICEPDS) as 'CEREALS' from ck group by $my_values" ;
          $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
        }}
```